# Динамический стор Ext js

Tags: java, extjs, treeview

Здравствуйте у меня возник одна проблема. Я делаю динамический `tree Store` на `Ext Js`, так вот наименования внутренних данных у меня на `.properties` файле записан. Подключить и выводить не проблема проблема в джава коде.

```
    ClsDTO clsDTO = new ClsDTO();                    
    clsDTO.setNameRu(properties.getProperty("monitoring.menumode.enum.Ru"));
    clsDTO.setNameRu(properties.getProperty("database.menumode.enum.Ru"));
    clsDTO.setNameRu(properties.getProperty("dataupload.menumode.enum.Ru"));
    answ.add(clsDTO);
```

тут все три значения использует один и тот же setter  а когда я его добавляю `answ.add(clsDTO);` так то самый последний только добавляется. Я понимаю что тут без фора или форича не обойтись но реализовать не получилось  .

```
 List<ClsDTO> answ = new ArrayList<ClsDTO>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял  `answ` у тебя массив?
Попробуй так:

```
 ClsDTO clsDTO = new ClsDTO();                    
    clsDTO.setNameRu(properties.getProperty("monitoring.menumode.enum.Ru"));
    answ.add(clsDTO); 

    clsDTO = new ClsDTO();    
    clsDTO.setNameRu(properties.getProperty("database.menumode.enum.Ru"));
    answ.add(clsDTO); 

    clsDTO = new ClsDTO();    
    clsDTO.setNameRu(properties.getProperty("dataupload.menumode.enum.Ru"));
    answ.add(clsDTO);
```